# Decoding base64 -> binary(octet stream) -> Image from palm software

Tags: android, binary, base64, hex

a client I'm building a site for needs the product images her field agents have on their palm software (through a third-party software). I contacted the technical support from said company and asked if the images are hosted on their server or if I can have csv/generated file with their locations.

As an answer, they said they don't store it in a db but instead send information to android which I can find in the ImageBytes section. When opening the document, I get a list of the ID, product name and what seems to be a `base64` string.

Here's an extract of one string(over 30k+ chars)

https://pastebin.com/KQ4QYbju

I tried loading it as a `<img src="data:image/png;base64,string>`, it obviously didn`t work.

I went to base64.guru and upon analysis, it seemed like it was a octet/stream; tried loading that, failed. 
Binary file. Tried downloading from base64 to .bin saved, went from bin -> bmp online converters and so on.

I read several answers on SO, and since it was on PALMS i assumed they might be bitmap files but that's honestly just a wild guess.

I've read about bitmapfactory and thought hey, maybe the output file is encoded in bitmapfactory and then just decoded.

Since I have no native Android/Java experience (just worked hybrid with ng/ionic on small projects), it just seems like I'm chasing ghosts at this point and the tech guy replies in 3-4 days.

Any idea on how I can at least understand what's happening or what I should be searching for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a hexedecimal encoded JPEG picture. Every byte is represented by two ASCII characters in [hexadecimal notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

It starts with 0x and it's followed by hexadecimal (0..9, A..F) digits.

The first 4 bytes `FFD8FFE0` are the typical start of the [JPEG header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure)

You can convert it with an online tool, eg. [this one](https://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_file.php?lang=en)

Comment: Thank you for the input, I've studied a bit more. My main idea was to convert the hex to base64 (after having removed the 0x); when doing so with an online converter (such as base64.guru or yours) it prints out the expected result and I can put in in an image format via base64.

However, when I set them up in a php array and do the same conversion, it just takes the code as strings, so the base64 output is unloadable. When I convert a single hex string line to ASCII in notepad++ then go for MIME -> base64 encode, all works well but yeah, limited to a line. The search continues. Thank you!